# What is the most efficient way to convert an array of 8 bit numbers to a long array of booleans and back in JavaScript;

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Uint8ClampedArray that looks something like this: `[0, 157, 28, 254...]`

I am looking for an efficient way to convert the numbers into boolean arrays (255 would be `[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]`) and merge those together.

What I have now kinda works (except it outputs strings of "0" and "1", not true and false, but i can work with that), but it is really slow:

```
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output = output.concat(input[i].toString(2).split(""));
}

return output;
```

How can I optimize this? (the expected length of the input array may be in the millions)
And is there a fast way to convert this bit array back into an Uint8ClampedArray in the same format?

Comment: Don't use `concat` to create new arrays over and over. Just `output.push(...…)`

Comment: Also use bit operations on the octets, not `toString(2)`

Comment: "*is there a fast way to convert this bit array back into an Uint8ClampedArray*" - if you want to convert back and forth, why do the conversion at all? What do you need the array of booleans for? It is a *very* inefficient representation of your data, especially for gigabytes of values!

Comment: woking on my answer a bit.. gimme 2 mins

Comment: bruh i just finished editing, look again smh

Comment: You can't convert this back to your input, because you lose the information which bit belongs to which number. To fix this, you'd need to pad every set of booleans to a fixed length. Which results in an overblown array which is basically represents what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an array to help map `1` and `0` to `true` and `false`

```js
var input=[0, 157, 28, 254];
function doIt(input){
  var output=input.map(a=>{
    return a.toString(2)
  })
  var mappingArr=[false,true]
  output=output.join('').split('').map(a=>mappingArr[a])
  return output;
}
console.log(doIt(input))
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all - the code is producing `["f","a","l","s","e"]` as the output

Comment: LOOK AGAIN i did say to wait :{

Comment: "*i did say to wait*" - what? where? why? I just saw a new answer popping up that didn't work so I commented on it. Please don't post untested code if you don't want it scrutinised immediately :-)

Comment: ik ik i thought it'd work flawlessly when i made an edit but i was clumsy i forgot an ordering

Comment: I can't mark your answer as correct, as I didn't ask the question. Also I don't think it's very efficient. (Sure, it no longer has the `O(n²)` complexity caused by the OPs `concat` usage, but nothing else improved)

Comment: it's fast though >:D